# How can I tell whether my 2D canvas is using hardware acceleration?

Tags: performance, firefox, html5-canvas

I'm creating a simple 2D game for learning canvas and game networking.

But it's very very slow on my crappy mobile phone and before optimizing its javascript I'd like to rule out other possible bottlenecks.

How can I figure out whether my game is slow because my canvas is rendering in software?

I didn't do anything special to turn on hardware acceleration, I'm just calling `drawImage` and `fillRect` to draw my stickmen and bullets.

Comment: Canvas will automatically use the GPU to hardware accelerate its drawings if a GPU is available. Canvas will be slower on less powerful mobile devices since they likely have less memory, less cpu available & probably no gpu to hardware accelerate canvas drawings.

Comment: My performance bottleneck turned out to be scaling up the canvas.

Comment: I asked this because I'd heard that Chrome wouldn't use hardware acceleration up until 256*256 canvases, and was suspicious that my canvas (which is 100*100) was also not being accelerated.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a comment above, canvas will be relatively slow on a less Graphic Intense Phones.

Below are just a few suggestion that might make your life a little easier when working with canvas.

- Use [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) Framework to built out your games, it uses PIXI to render graphics on Canvas which makes use of WebGL and make canvas a fallback option.
- Check out [CrossWalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) it is Chrome Run-time Compiled for Android into a package, which improves canvas's and HTML5 app performance by a lot.